# static function lookup from a template function issue with xlC

Tags: c++, templates, name-lookup, xlc

While I was searching for clues about a compilation problem I have had in my source, I have come across this [bug report (against Mozilla's JavaScript engine source)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=587103) related to functions lookup. Quoting from the bug report:

> TypedArrayTemplate is (obviously) a template, and it is referencing INT_TO_JSVAL, a static inline function, without prefixing it with "::". This breaks xlC because it can not resolve INT_TO_JSVAL. The standard does not require that statics be considered if the unqualified name is not found in the context of the template arguments. g++ does this fallback, xlC does not.

Informative message from the compiler:

```
(I) Static declarations are not considered for a function call if the function is not qualified.
```

In my case the code that was failing was similar to this:

```
namespace N
{

static bool foo (std::string const &);

template <typename T>
void bar (T const &, std::string const & s)
{
    // expected unqualified call to N::foo()
    foo (s);
}

void baz (std::string const & s)
{
    bar (s);
}

} // namespace N
```

Is the behaviour that xlC implements really correct? Where does the 2003 or 2011 standard talk about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prior to C++11 this was the correct behavior: unqualified name resolution of names used in templates was defined to only find functions with external linkage.

C++03 section 14.6.4.2 Candidate Functions [temp.dep.candidate] paragraph 1:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, if the function name is an unqualified-id but not a
>   template-id, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations with external
>     linkage from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations with external
>     linkage found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

which changes in C++11 to:

> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the candidate functions are found using the usual
>   lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1) or qualified name lookup (3.4.3), only
>     function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in
>     either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

Comment: Do I read correctly that C++11 drops the external linkage requirement?

Comment: This answer could use a summary.

Answer (score 4):

V12.1 of the compiler has the new behaviour by default.

If you are using an earlier version of the xlC compiler use option `-qdebug=KeepUnqualifiedStaticCandidate`